# Using Twig in Laravel 5 without TwigBridge?

Tags: laravel, twig

I'm creating a CMS using Laravel.  I'd like to use Twig markup in the "page templates" - which are editable by users and stored in the database.  The CMS *application* will still use Blade.

I don't want to use TwigBridge since, in my understanding, it will force me to use Twig for everything.  For example, in the TwigBridge documentation is states:

> You call the Twig template like you would any other view:
>
> // Without the file extension
>
> View::make('i_am_twig', [...])

Instead, I want my views to continue to use blade templates, but use Twig for parsing the user-editable page templates.  Perhaps it would look something like this:

```
Twig::make('i_am_twig', [...])
```

Is this possible?  Step-by-step instructions would be highly appreciated!

I understand that some people might suggest that I choose only one: *Use blade templates or twig templates for everything*.  But please, let's not get into that debate here.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, but I'll post it as a placeholder until a better answer comes around.  I'm not well versed in Laravel Packages yet, otherwise I would have taken that route.  Here's how I did it:

**Step #1**: In composer.json..

Add "twig/twig": "~1.0" to the require section:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "twig/twig": "~1.0"            <=========== add this
},
```

And also to the Autoload section:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models",
        "app",
        "database/seeds",
        "vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php"   <==== add this             
    ],
```

**Step #2**: Update Composer:

```
> sudo composer update
> composer dump-autoload
```

**Step #3**: Create the following folder/file: /resources/views/twig/hello.html

```
Well hello everyone!
```

**Step #4**: Render the template:

```
    \Twig_Autoloader::register();

    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(app_path() . '/../resources/views/twig');
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);

    echo $twig->render('hello.html', array('debug' => true));
```

Comment: How did you end up going with this? I am looking at doing something similar but with emails and CMS content. Any issues? Manage to get it rendering from a string?

Comment: @Wizzard: I eventually abandon that architecture and started using the October CMS.  I never could figure out how to get Twig to render from a string.  From what I had found online, there was no way without hacking Twig itself, which appeared to be very complicated.

Comment: Intersting... I saw this and thought it might do the job; https://techpunch.co.uk/development/render-string-twig-template-symfony2